# ComboBox binding to SelectedValue does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, enums

I needed to bind a ComboBox to enum values and followed several ideas from so. I ended up with the simplest solution I could find and which should fit all my needs, except it is not working completely, but it should...

Heres what I'am doing:
I need the ComboBox within a DataGrid cell, so I defined a DataGridTemplateColumn for that

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="150" Header="Data-Type">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDataType,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataTypeValues}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In my ViewModel I populate the enum values

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> DataTypeValues
{
    get
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyType)).Cast<MyType>().ToList<MyType>();
    }
}
```

And have a property for the selected value

```
MyType _selectedType;
public MyType SelectedDataType
{
    get { return _selectedType; }
    set
    {
        _selectedType = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The ComboBox is filled with my enum values as I expected, but when I select another value, the SelectedDataType's setter is not called, meaning I have no information which Item is currently selected. I also tried to use a SelectedItem binding instead of SelectedValue but that does not work either.

What I'am missing here?

edit: typo

EDIT2:
--------UPDATE--------

Now I created a sample WPF Application to reproduce my problem. Only used the relevant code parts in there, and theres the same problem. Heres the full source code of that example:

Xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParameter, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="150" Header="Data-Type">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataTypeValues}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And the .cs file:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new Viewmodel();
        DataContext = vm;
    }
}

class Viewmodel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Viewmodel()
    {
        Parameters = new ObservableCollection<Parameter>();
        Parameters.Add(new Parameter());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Parameter> Parameters
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    public Parameter SelectedParameter { get; set; }
}

class Parameter : ViewModelBase
{
    MyType _selectedType;
    public MyType SelectedType
    {
        get { return _selectedType; }
        set
        {
            _selectedType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyType> DataTypeValues
    {
        get { return Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyType)).Cast<MyType>(); }
    }
}

public enum MyType
{
    INT,
    DOUBLE,
    REAL,
    STRING
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(bool validateFields = true, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
}
```

Comment: I tried more variations, but it seems like the problem is the usage of the ComboBox within the DataGrid. The above viewmodel code works nicely when I use the ComboBox at another part within my application. But when I define the CellTemplate of the DataGridColumn and use the ComboBox there along with the posted code behind, the binding to the selected value does not work as described.... any ideas? Something wrong with my XAML?

Comment: Check now. I have updated the answer. It is working fine from my side.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT : **

Yes I got the issue now. Your code is not working since are binding `SelectedValue`

Instead bind `SelectedItem` property and check. It should work.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="150" Header="Data-Type">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataType,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataTypeValues}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried that now, but still same result. I get the values into the ComboBox, but the binding to the SelectedItem or SelectedValue does not work either with that approach :-/

Comment: Check now. I have updated the answer. It is working fine from my side.

Comment: Did you check this

Comment: Yes I did. As you can see in my updated question I provided an complete example which does not work for me. And there I already used your suggestion and bind to SelectedItem. Does my posted example code work for you? Then there must be a problem with my installation or anything else...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are binding the selected item inside the window viewmodel,make binding inside the datagrid . below code worked for me.

XAML:

```
 <DataGrid Name="datagrid" ItemsSource="{Binding List,Mode=TwoWay}"   >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Height="22" 
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.DataTypeValues,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window,
                                                                                        AncestorLevel=1}}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataType,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>               

                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```
 private List<ListItems> list;

        public List<ListItems> List
        {
            get { return list; }
            set
            {
                list = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("List");
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<MyType> DataTypeValues
        {
            get
            {
                return Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyType)).Cast<MyType>().ToList<MyType>();
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            List = new List<ListItems>();
            List.Add(new ListItems());
            List.Add(new ListItems());

        }
```

Grid Items:

```
public class ListItems 
    {

        MyType _selectedType;
        public MyType SelectedDataType
        {
            get { return _selectedType; }
            set
            {
                _selectedType = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedDataType");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use element name while binding to selectedvalue property or selectedItem like

```
 <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Height="22" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.DataTypeValues,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window,
                                                                                    AncestorLevel=1}}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataType,ElementName="datagrid",UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Dont understand that... how should that binding work... Binding the SelectedItem of my ComboBox to the parent DataGrid SelectedItem. Makes no sense to me...

Comment: sorry for late response but, that works for me  when you bind your component with parent component's data context then child will automatically inherit parent's data context.